# HTACCESS config in running 2 Joomla sites in one domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I am working on a new Joomla3 website for a client. Their current site is in www.domain.com/current/index.php (var/www/current) so without messing up the current site I added another directory to where I uploaded the file for the new site www.domain.com/newsite/index.php (var/www/newsite) and whenever I browse, I land on the site I am working on, and all the links work just fine.

The problem is when I try to login to the site using the Login Module, after logging in, I am redirected to the current website. Not the site I am working on.

I have no access to the httpd.conf file so I need to change the HTACCESS file.

Here's the current HTACCESS file in both site (/var/www/.htaccess)

```
<Files .htaccess>
   order allow,deny
   deny from all
</Files>

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|pl|txt)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php

ErrorDocument 400 https://www.domain.org/errors/400.html
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.domain.org/errors/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.domain.org/errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 https://www.domain.org/errors/500.html
```

Answer (score 0):

**Original**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

**Edited**

```
RewriteBase /newsite/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /newsite/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Would this mess up the current site's login when users login to their accounts? If it does then I can't do this.

Comment: this one would not mess up current login. because it separate by rewritebase. rewritebase = subfolder